# Finite potential well as potential goes to infinity and width to zero

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I am studying the solutions of the finite potential well and I came over the following question:

> "What happens if we put the potential to infinity, but at the same time make the well thinner and thinner $(a \rightarrow 0)$ ?"

In this case we can’t have any solution for the wave function, right?
Because if we make the well very thin towards zero, the the space between energy levels gets infinitely high.

But it still seems weird. Are my suggestions correct?

Comment: Check [Delta potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential#Double_delta_potential)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: So will the wave function look like this: for $x<0$ it’s a positive real exponential that goes to infinity near to 0 and for $x>0$ it’s a negative exponential that goes to infinity near 0. So it is not defined at $x=0$ because the potential is infinity but we can normalise it since it goes to 0 for x to pos or beg infinity. Am I Right?

Comment: @RogerVadim On the website they only look at the finite delta potential a*delta(x)

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it.

Comment: It depends on the limit of the ratio between the depth of the potential and its width $a$. If it converges to some constant $\mu$, we expect to retrieve the delta function potential $V(x) = -\mu \delta(x)$. If the ratio goes to $+\infty$, we expect no bound state, with the argument in OP (so just a free particle). If the ratio goes to $0$,  I think the limit is ill defined.